# Android - ProgressBar work half the time

Tags: android, progress-bar

I want to display a progressbar when my activity load. But the progressbar work only half the time and when the progressbar doesn't work a black screen was display while charging.

This is my AsyncTask:

```
class Task extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Boolean> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        titre_projet.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        description_projet.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        image_projet.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        titre_projet.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        description_projet.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        image_projet.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {

        try {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Intent intent = getIntent();

                    if (intent != null) {
                        searchResultats(intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_PROJET));
                    }
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

In this code, all in `runOnUiThread` is my code to display the content.

This is what I have in OnCreate:

```
    image_projet = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView_projet);
    layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.progressbar_view);
    titre_projet = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.titre_projet);
    description_projet = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.description_projet);
    new Task().execute();
```

And my XML for the progressBar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:pivotX="50%" android:pivotY="50%" android:fromDegrees="0"
android:toDegrees="360"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<shape android:shape="ring" android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
    android:thicknessRatio="8" android:useLevel="false">

    <size android:width="76dip" android:height="76dip" />
    <gradient android:type="sweep" android:useLevel="false"
        android:startColor="#447a29"
        android:endColor="#447a29"
        android:angle="0"
        />
</shape>
</rotate>
```

Comment: What is the point of the AsyncTask if everything inside doInBackground run on the UI Thread ?

Comment: I've add the IU Thread because without I have an error "Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views."

Comment: Yes, you can't modify a View if you are not on the UI Thread. But, the point of the AsyncTask class is to run on another Thread, to avoid to block the UI thread. For example, every time you would block the Thread (network call, file reading, expensive computation), use an AsyncTask.

Comment: So, how I can delete the RunOnUIThread to run my ProgressBar and to run my activity that modify my View too ?

Comment: What do you mean by "when my activity load" ? What does your Activity load ? If you want to show a ProgressBar to your user, simply use : 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html

Comment: My app is a News Reader. So when user clic on a news title, the news activity with the content of the article load. I have try to do the ProgressBar with Thread but it doesn't work. I don't know how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your News Activity starts, start to fetch your data (article). In the onCreate method of Activity, start your task. In the doInBackground method of your Task, fetch the article (I assume you'll need to fetch it through network).
Once your Task is done, update your UI in onPostExecute.

```
class Task extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Object> {

    private Activity activity;

    public Task(Activity a){
       activity=a;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object article) {
       activity.onArticleFetched(article);
    }

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(String... params) {
       Object article = new Article();             
       //Fetch article... may take a few seconds, but you don't care because you are not in the UI thread
       return article;
    }
}
```

In the  Activity, do something like this :

```
class NewsActivity extends Activity {

     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle a){
       super.onCreate(a);
       //do some stuff.
       task.execute();
       progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     }

     public void onArticleFetched(Object article){
       progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
       //updateUI
     }
}
```

Comment: Ok, I just understand how it works ! Thank you so mutch !

Answer (score 1):

1. You have published `drawable` instead of `layout` xml. I haven't any guess how it can be used for indicating progress.
2. Please check [AsyncTask reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). `AsyncTask.doInBackground()` should be used for obtaining data (networking, parsing and other stuff prohibited in the UI thread). There you time to time need to call `AsyncTask.publishProgress()` and after that system calls `AsyncTask.onProgressUpdate()` in the UI thread. Override `AsyncTask.onProgressUpdate()` to show progress in your UI (set level to progress bar or something else).
3. At the end `AsyncTask.onPostExecute()` will be called in the UI thread. Override this method to show data processed in `AsyncTask.doInBackground()` and modify views as much as you wish.